# How to convert XML to Object in java?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I am working on converting XML to object and object XML . When i try to convert my XML to object which has nested of same object but unable to achieve could anybody please tell me how to achieve this in spring. Below is my XML ,

```
    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<ProductHierarchyDTO>
    <id>45</id>
    <szName>LIB-pappu</szName>
    <szDescription>LIB-pappu</szDescription>
    <iParentid>30003305</iParentid>
    <cIsActive>Y</cIsActive>
    <cIsProduct>N</cIsProduct>
    <productHierarchyList>
        <ProductHierarchyDTO>
            <id>48</id>
            <szName>LIB-pappu-123</szName>
            <szDescription>LIB-pappu-123</szDescription>
            <iParentid>45</iParentid>
            <cIsActive>Y</cIsActive>
            <cIsProduct>Y</cIsProduct>
        </ProductHierarchyDTO>
        <ProductHierarchyDTO>
            <id>49</id>
            <szName>LIB-pappu-321</szName>
            <szDescription>LIB-pappu-123</szDescription>
            <iParentid>45</iParentid>
            <cIsActive>Y</cIsActive>
            <cIsProduct>Y</cIsProduct>
        </ProductHierarchyDTO>
    </productHierarchyList>
</ProductHierarchyDTO>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try so far? code please

Comment: The following will help:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: try{
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductHierarchyDTO.class);
jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
ProductHierarchyDTO productHierarchyDTO = (ProductHierarchyDTO) 
      jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(productHierarchyDTO, System.out);
  }catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 0):

The Java XMLStreamReader class allows you to manipulate XML documents. You can use it to extract the information you want from the XML and create Java objects with it. Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html.

Answer (score 0):

With JAXB you could model your class like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="ProductHierarchyDTO")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ProductHierarchyDTO {

    private int id;

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElementRef
    private List<ProductHierarchyDTO> productHierarchyList;

}
```